# Potential of the case of OS-CON capacitor

Tags: capacitor

I am developing the board having *through-hole* OS-CON capacitors very close together up to them having a contact with each other. I recall that "regular" electrolytic capacitors may have potential on their case relative to the terminals (see [this document from Nichicon](https://www.nichicon.co.jp/english/products/pdf/aluminum.pdf), page 9 item 7). I have never experienced the issues because caps are usually put into the protective sleeve.

However OS-CON are not put into the sleeve, and nothing is mentioned in the [product catalog](http://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/AAB8000/AAB8000COL87.pdf).

Did you see any information or precautions regarding OS-CON family capacitor case potential? I can not find any relevant data in the device datasheet, product catalog, packaging, soldering and safety documents.

Comment: I never even knew OS-CON cases might be connected to a terminal...I should test the ones at work on Monday.

Comment: They are covered with a clear protective varnish. Try to poke them with multimeter probes, it won't make contact unless you scratch the varnish off. I don't know if this is specified as an insulator though, might cause problems if caps rub against each other due to vibration.

Comment: All (or most) thru-holes have a polymer cover over them.  You probably are going to have a look at the actual parts you are going to use.